# Turning my own character into animation

Tags: modeling, animation

I'm a completely new blender user! I want to change my own drawing (on paper) into animation using blender. Is it possible? and if yes how should i start?

Comment: You need to model, rig and animate the model.

Comment: Well how should i start?

Comment: [This might get you started](http://www.blendernation.com/2012/01/09/2d-in-blender-2-6-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its definitely possible.

1. you've got to model your drawing.

   - how to model

     1. When I start creating a character, I draw it on a paper how its supposed to look from the front, then how its supposed to look from the side.
     2. Then you put your drawing as a background image in blender and model the mesh along the lines of your drawing.
2. give it an armature, that armature acts as the skeleton of your model and you can animate the bones of that armature.